# Firefox error in headless selenium testing

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, firefox, headless

I have a question regarding a scraping script I'm trying to run on a remote server with ssh access. I use the Firefox headless browser with Xvfb to run my tests, but recently I've run into a problem that I am unable to solve. I have two similar scripts that try and get the angular scope to get the data that is loaded into the page, but with one of the scripts I receive a firefox error.

The two pages have asynchronous loading so with both I wait for the relevant objects to load but on one site, before the objects are loaded, firefox crashes.

Locally on my windows 7 PC with the same firefox version (46.0) everything works fine. I am able to create screenshots of the situation on the remote server after the firefox crash, a screenshot is shown below.

[Firefox error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THHA8.png)

The code which i use to retrieve the angular object is:

```
driver.execute_script("return JSON.stringify(angular.element('.ev-container-overzicht').scope().producten)")
```

I've also tried to apply a Firefox profile to initialize some settings without any luck. The code for creating the profile:

```
firefoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefoxProfile.set_preference('webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer', False)
firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
firefoxProfile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so','false')
firefoxProfile.set_preference("http.response.timeout", 10)
firefoxProfile.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time", 10)
firefoxProfile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", True)
firefoxProfile.set_preference("typeerror.enabled", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefoxProfile)
```

(I added the typeerror.enabled = True as a guess because that is what the error was about, does not make a difference whether it is true or false).

I have not tried it in a different browser yet (phantomjs or chrome), that will be my next step. I hope it will work in Firefox, though.

*The server runs Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.*

*Edit:*

Let my try and explain the problem a little bit better. I have a website, easyswitch.nl that allows users to fill in a form and compare the results. I am trying to automatize this process by running selenium.

**Locally, the situation is as follows:**

I can't add more than 2 links so ill explain in words:
- The form on the main page (easyswitch.nl) is filled in
- A spinner starts and an ajax call is made to retrieve the angular object.
[The objects are loaded and can be scraped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/063dS.png)

The angular object is scraped by running a javascript command and parsing this to json with the lines:

```
data = driver.execute_script("return JSON.stringify(angular.element('.ev-  container-overzicht').scope().producten)")
products = json.loads(data.encode('utf-8'))
```

After this i can access all data through the products object. Again, locally this works fine in both the Firefox browser and Phantomjs browser. Phantomjs browser log:

```
[INFO  - 2016-05-26T08:28:28.560Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 55615
[INFO  - 2016-05-26T08:28:28.910Z] Session [d2cb0b30-231b-11e6-9fcb-6d88687426db] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2016-05-26T08:28:28.910Z] Session [d2cb0b30-231b-11e6-9fcb-6d88687426db] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2016-05-26T08:28:28.910Z] Session [d2cb0b30-231b-11e6-9fcb-6d88687426db] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"2.1.1","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.2.0","platform":"windows-8.1-32bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"},"phantomjs.page.settings.webStorageEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2016-05-26T08:28:28.910Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: d2cb0b30-231b-11e6-9fcb-6d88687426db
                                                                                                                                           [INFO  - 2016-05-26T08:32:53.714Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _cleanupWindowlessSessions - Asynchronous Sessions clean-up phase starting NOW
```

**On the server, the situation is as follows:**

*Firefox*
The same happens when run locally, the form is filled in and the compare button is pressed, the spinner starts loading but the angular object is never loaded and after a while firefox crashes with the error as shown above (first image).

Firefox log:
I am not sure where i can find the logs of Firefox when running headless, some tips here maybe?

*Phantomjs*
The same happens as with Firefox, only phantomjs doesn't crash but just keeps loading infinitely until a manual cut-off point is reached.

Phantomjs log:

```
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
[INFO  - 2016-05-26T09:04:15.651Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 43616
[INFO  - 2016-05-26T09:04:16.527Z] Session [d2dfb260-2320-11e6-a24b-9798e4d4ca10] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.8 Safari/534.34","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2016-05-26T09:04:16.527Z] Session [d2dfb260-2320-11e6-a24b-9798e4d4ca10] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2016-05-26T09:04:16.541Z] Session [d2dfb260-2320-11e6-a24b-9798e4d4ca10] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"1.9.8","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.1.0","platform":"linux-unknown-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2016-05-26T09:04:16.541Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: d2dfb260-2320-11e6-a24b-9798e4d4ca10
```

I've also tried to play with the settings in Phantomjs by adding the following lines of code to the driver initialization:

```
cap = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS.copy()        cap['phantomjs.page.settings.webStorageEnabled'] = True
cap['phantomjs.page.settings.applicationCacheEnabled'] = True
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=cap)
```

Without any luck. I hope this information will give more insights!

Comment: I don't see a screenshot. Also what's the error? You must have some kind of traceback or logs. And can we see what the website is?

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to add the link to the screenshot, it is in now. Thanks for the response btw! The website is easyswitch.nl. You have to fill in the form on the right and press the button to compare. After pressing the button the angular object is loaded and used to fill in the view of the site.

Comment: Still need more information. Show us more code. Add logs if you can. What makes you even think that the line of code you've included is where the error happens?